# RAC 4 Swift Failed method

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

ReactiveCocoa 4 has a method on the `SignalProducer` class, `then` that waits for the producer to completed and replaces it with another producer like so:

`someProducer.then(replacementProducer)`.

However what I want is a method that waits until the original producer errors out and then replaces it with the second producer (doing nothing on completion events).

`then` is implemented as (note next events are not forwarded):

```
public func then<U>(replacement: SignalProducer<U, Error>) -> SignalProducer<U, Error> {
    let relay = SignalProducer<U, Error> { observer, observerDisposable in
        self.startWithSignal { signal, signalDisposable in
            observerDisposable.addDisposable(signalDisposable)

            signal.observe { event in
                switch event {
                case let .Failed(error):
                    observer.sendFailed(error)
                case .Completed:
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                case .Interrupted:
                    observer.sendInterrupted()
                case .Next:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return relay.concat(replacement)
}
```

What I want would look similar except on failure, instead of sending an error, it would send a completed signal. More specifically the switch statement would change to look like:

```
signal.observe { event in
    switch event {
        case .Failed:
            observer.sendCompleted()
        case .Completed, .Next: break
        case .Interrupted:
            observer.sendInterrupted()
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1) Is this valid? It works as I would expect, the replacement signal is only started when the first signal errors out.
2) Is there a better way to do it so that the error information doesn't get lost?

An example of where I would use this is a two-step authentication process:

`self.verifyToken(token).failed(self.revalidateSession())`

If the token verification succeeds, all is good and no need to revalidate. If it fails, then revalidation needs to occur.

EDIT:

I changed the signal observation block so that if the first signal completes with no error, it starts the replacement signal with `startWithComplete` so that completion events are forwarded down the chain without triggering any action from the signal.

That makes it easy to do this:

`self.verify(token).failed(self.refreshSession(token)).then(self.fetchUserForToken(token))`

where `then` is chained and only gets executed when either `verify` or `refreshSession` is successful.

```
signal.observe { event in
    switch event {
        case .Failed:
            observer.sendCompleted()
        case .Completed:
            replacement.startWithCompleted {}
        case .Next: break
        case .Interrupted:
            observer.sendInterrupted()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Is this valid?

No. If your verifying signal producer sends a normal value and completes, your replacement signal producer does start (by the `startWithCompleted` call) but will produce nothing (since you are not observing anything in the `startWithCompleted` closure, and the inner `replay` signal producer will never terminate).

2) Is there a better way?

You can use `flatMapError` operator, this way you can also get the error information.

```
self.verify(token)
    .map { _ in () }
    .flatMapError { error in
        return self.refreshSession(token).map { _ in () }
    }
```

Note, The two `map { _ in () }` can be omitted if the `veriy` producer and `refreshSession` producer produce values of the same type.

Comment: So then could I rewrite my `failed` method simply using `map` and `flatMapError`?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to also observe the success signal of the original signal producer